# Plotting 3 d pie chart using jqplot

Tags: javascript, jqplot

In my application i have to plot the 3 D pie chart for showing the market research data. I have previously worked on the jqplot for bar and line graph. so i planned to use the same one for this. i have tried to find the 3 D pie in the jqplot but unable to do it. Can we have the 3 D pie chart in jqplot. Any other free java script plotting framework available for doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems as though JQPlot does support pie charts, see here: [Pie & Donut charts](http://www.jqplot.com/tests/pie-donut-charts.php)

There are other alternatives (like amCharts - [3D pie chart](http://www.amcharts.com/demos/3d-pie-chart/)), but I'd stick with the free stuff personally. You could dress up those JQPlot pie charts nicely with just the right use of colours ;).